# jQuery Bootgrid's pagination is not working?

Tags: jquery

I've taken the code from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZM8LW/29/):

```
var public_spreadsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10v53Z7jR6qCaPnAHdPk8qLktHYzQtvhvVhQpxqgbJO8/pubhtml";

function init() {
    Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
                    callback: showInfo,
                    simpleSheet: true } );
}


function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
    data = tabletop.sheets("Devices").all();

    for (var key in data[1]) {
        var type = (key === 'rowNumber') ? ' data-type="numeric"' : '';
        $("#main-table thead tr").append('<th data-column-id="' + key + '"' + type + '>' + key + '</th>');
    }

    $("#main-table").bootgrid().bootgrid("append", data);

}

init();
```

and implemented it on my [page](http://www.crystalball.tv/compatible-handsets-test1-0#2).

But the pagination is not working, and yet it works fine on the jsFiddle example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an incompatibility with certain CMSes and jQuery Bootgrid. The following line in the Bootgrid source, and similar lines involving finding anchor hrefs, have to be modified:

```
 var command = $this.attr("href").substr(1);
```

to something like:

```
 var href = $this.attr("href");
 var command = (href ? href : $this.find('a').attr('href')).substr(1);
```

or else `substr` will be called on an `undefined` href attribute for an `undefined` element.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with debug tools in your browser? I checked your site and you have several errors logged out there...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
>   http://www.google.com/ads/user-lists/1006861511/?fmt=1&num=1&cv=7&frm=0&url…tions/27783726/jquery-bootgrids-pagination-is-not-working&random=609575088
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Useing Google Chrome, right click the page and select inspect element, then select Console to see the errors.

Comment: Thanks tintyethan yes I see that error message. But it's weird I'm getting that when I'm using the same files as being used in the jsFiddle?

Comment: I'm looking through the code, but it looks like you have a bad reference somewhere - you're pointing to a url/resource incorrectly.

Comment: I'm not finding any problems, so I think it may be some sort of conflict with other scripts on that page. Could you try adding this to a separate page on your site to verify that it works by itself on your domain.

Comment: Will look at implementing this tomorrow and will report back.